# Ansible "Could not resolve hostname" error for host user@ip_address

Tags: ssh, ansible

while running this...

```
$ ansible all -m ping
```

I am getting this...

```
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [test@172.31.48.154]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [test@172.31.48.154]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information

test@172.31.48.154 | FAILED! => {
  "failed": true,
  "msg": "failed to transfer file to /home/test/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-148610479.7-240708330710714/ping.py:\n\nssh: Could not resolve hostname 172.31.48.154]:Name or service not known\r\nlost connection\n"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
  "changed": false,
  "ping": "pong"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `username@host` is not supported in the inventory.  See issue [`#14255`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14255).

Instead, you can write your inventory file like:

```
host.example.com     ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_user=test
```

Or run your command like:

```
$ ansible all -m ping -u test
```

Comment: I was struggling with the same errors (while running a different ansible command) for the last two days. Your answer solved it (and brought me to another issue). Thank you!